# How to convert a mac address to floating value?

Tags: encryption

I want to change a mac address to floating point number.

I tried using IEEE 754 converter online, but it says "the value is out of range".

How can I do this in a proper way?

Comment: Not sure why this question was migrated - are you wanting to write some code to do this or do you simply want the answer?

Answer (score 1):

[From Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=440768)

```
# ORIGINAL VIA PERLMONKS
sub mac_hex2num {
  my $mac_hex = shift;

  $mac_hex =~ s/://g;

  $mac_hex = substr(('0'x12).$mac_hex, -12);
  my @mac_bytes = unpack("A2"x6, $mac_hex);

  my $mac_num = 0;
  foreach (@mac_bytes) {
    $mac_num = $mac_num * (2**8) + hex($_);
  }

  return $mac_num;
}


sub mac_num2hex {
  my $mac_num = shift;

  my @mac_bytes;
  for (1..6) {
    unshift(@mac_bytes, sprintf("%02x", $mac_num % (2**8)));
    $mac_num = int($mac_num / (2**8));
  }

  return join(':', @mac_bytes);
}


chomp(my $inmac = shift @ARGV);
my $mac = mac_hex2num($inmac);
print "$inmac converted to a decimal: $mac\n";
my $outmac = mac_num2hex($mac);
print "$mac converted to hex: $outmac\n";
```

Tested:

```
$ perl mac2num 00:00:DE:AD:BE:EF
00:00:DE:AD:BE:EF converted to a decimal: 3735928559
3735928559 converted to hex: 00:00:de:ad:be:ef
```